# Returning "Null" in sql pulls

Tags: sql, vb.net

I don't really know if any source code will help here... But how come when I run my SQL query with a join that every column after about 70 rows gets returned as "Null". Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
P_DATA.MATERIALID, 
T_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYGROUPID,
T_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYTYPEID,
T_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYTYPEDESCRIPTION

FROM 
P_DATA

LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPLATE_GROUP_PROPERTIES
ON (P_DATA.MATERIALID = T_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYGROUPID)
OR (P_DATA.MATERIALID = T_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYTYPEID)
OR (CAST(P_DATA.MATERIALID AS CHAR(2000)) =  T_GROUP_PROPERTIES.PROPERTYTYPEDESCRIPTION)
```

Comment: Because your table, `p_data`, has one or more rows that are filled with `NULL` values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's the thing though, there are no null values in the `p_data` table, its only when it gets returned in the sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the outer join that's giving you extra NULLs.  *ALL* rows from P_DATA will be represented in the results, even if they have no matching row in TEMPLATE_GROUP_PROPERTIES.  The query generates NULLs in the output to represent the lack of matching data in the joined table.

Change LEFT OUTER JOIN to INNER JOIN to get rid of the NULLs